# get user input value from textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-input

I have asp.net-c# application.
I am displaying 2 sections. Bottom portion is a gridview of DB records. Upper portion is textboxes showing values of the highlighted row in the gridview.,
When a value in the textboxes and then the save button clisked I want to update DB and gridview with new value.

I am not sure how to get the new value. I tried the following:

Web Form code:

```
    namespace Productivity_ASPWeb
{
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
#region Public Methods
public static DateTime FirstOfMonth(this DateTime dt)
{
return (dt.AddDays(1 - dt.Day)).AtMidnight();
}
public static DateTime FirstOfMonth(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
DateTime firstDayOfMonth = dt.FirstOfMonth();
return (firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek ? firstDayOfMonth :
firstDayOfMonth.NextDayOfWeek(dayOfWeek)).AtMidnight();
}
public static DateTime LastOfMonth(this DateTime dt)
{
int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month);
return dt.FirstOfMonth().AddDays(daysInMonth - 1).AtMidnight();
}
public static DateTime LastOfMonth(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
DateTime lastDayOfMonth = dt.LastOfMonth();
return lastDayOfMonth.AddDays(lastDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek < dayOfWeek ?
dayOfWeek - lastDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek - 7 :
dayOfWeek - lastDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek);
}
public static DateTime NextDayOfWeek(this DateTime dt, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
int offsetDays = dayOfWeek - dt.DayOfWeek;
return dt.AddDays(offsetDays > 0 ? offsetDays : offsetDays + 7).AtMidnight();
}
public static DateTime AtMidnight(this DateTime dt)
{
return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, 0, 0, 0);
}
public static DateTime AtMidday(this DateTime dt)
{
return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, 12, 0, 0);
}
#endregion
}
public partial class DM_Credits : System.Web.UI.Page
{
public SQLControl SQL = new SQLControl(GlobalVariables.strConnection);
private int intSelectedRow = 0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!Page.IsPostBack)  
{
if (!Page.IsPostBack)   
{
txtSrchStart_Date.Text = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(-2).ToShortDateString();
txtSrchEnd_Date.Text = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString();
}
if (GlobalVariables.updatetype == "")
btnSearchCredits_Click(null, EventArgs.Empty);
dgvCredits.SelectRow(GlobalVariables.oldrowindex);
GlobalVariables.oldrowindex = dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
txtOldRowIndex.Value = dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex.ToString();
if (int.TryParse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart(), out GlobalVariables.oldrowindex))
{
dgvCredits.SelectRow(int.Parse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart()));
}
}
else
{
GlobalVariables.oldrowindex = dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
txtOldRowIndex.Value = dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex.ToString();
btnSearchCredits_Click(null, EventArgs.Empty);
}
}

public void CreditsLoadGrid(string query = "")
{
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
{
SQL.ExecuteQuery("Select Credits_ID, Credible_ID, ADP_ID, Employee_ID, Start_Date, End_Date, Reason, Units, Percentage, Other, RecordActive, CreatedBy, CreateDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate from Credits where (@Start_Date = '' or Start_Date = @Start_Date) or (@End_Date = '' or End_Date = @End_Date) order by Credible_ID, Start_Date;");
}
else
{
SQL.ExecuteQuery(query);
}

if (SQL.HasException(true))
return;
dgvCredits.DataSource = SQL.DBDS.Tables[0];
dgvCredits.DataBind();

if (dgvCredits.Rows.Count > 0)
{
{
if (int.TryParse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart(), out GlobalVariables.oldrowindex))
{
dgvCredits.SelectRow(int.Parse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart()));
dgvCredits.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart());
}
else
{
dgvCredits.SelectRow(0);
dgvCredits.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
}
}

if (dgvCredits.Rows.Count > 0)
{
dgvCredits_SelectionChanged(null, EventArgs.Empty);
intSelectedRow = dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
intSelectedRow = dgvCredits.SelectedIndex;

if (dgvCredits.Rows.Count > 0)
{
intSelectedRow = dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
if (int.TryParse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart(), out GlobalVariables.oldrowindex))
{

if (dgvCredits.Rows.Count >= int.Parse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart()))
{
dgvCredits.SelectRow(int.Parse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart()));
dgvCredits.SelectedIndex = int.Parse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart());
dgvCredits.SelectedRow.Focus();
DisplayValues(); 
}
}
}
else
{
intSelectedRow = dgvCredits.Rows.Count;
txtCredits_ID.Text = "";
txtCredible_ID.Text = "";
txtADP_ID.Text = "";
txtCredits_ID.Text = "";
txtEmployee_ID.Text = "";
txtStart_Date.Text = "";
txtEnd_Date.Text = "";
txtReason.Text = "";
txtUnits.Text = "";
txtPercentage.Text = "";
txtOther.Text = "";
txtCreatedBy.Text = "";
txtCreateDate.Text = "";
txtModifiedBy.Text = "";
txtModifiedDate.Text = "";
chkbxRecordActive.Checked = false;
}
}
}

protected void dgvCredits_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
e.Row.Cells[11].Visible = false;
e.Row.Cells[12].Visible = false;
e.Row.Cells[13].Visible = false;
e.Row.Cells[14].Visible = false;
}

protected void dgvCredits_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
// 0 [Credits_ID]
e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Credits ID";
e.Row.Cells[0].Width = 75;
// 1 [Credible_ID]
e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Credible ID";
e.Row.Cells[1].Width = 75;
// 2 [ADP_ID]
e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "ADP ID";
e.Row.Cells[2].Width = 50;
// 3 [Employee_ID]
e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "Emp ID";
e.Row.Cells[3].Width = 50;
//dgvCredits.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Emp ID";
// dgvCredits.Columns[3].Width = 50;
// 4 [Start_Date]
e.Row.Cells[4].Text = "Start Date";
e.Row.Cells[4].Width = 170;
// 5 [End_Date]
e.Row.Cells[5].Text = "End Date";
e.Row.Cells[5].Width = 170;
e.Row.Cells[6].Text = "Reason";
e.Row.Cells[6].Width = 350;
e.Row.Cells[7].Text = "Units";
e.Row.Cells[7].Width = 60;
// 8 [Percentage]
e.Row.Cells[8].Text = "%";
e.Row.Cells[8].Width = 60;
// 9 [Other]
e.Row.Cells[9].Text = "Other";
e.Row.Cells[9].Width = 170;
// 10 [RecordActive]
e.Row.Cells[10].Text = "Record Active";
e.Row.Cells[10].Width = 50;
}

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(dgvCredits, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
}
}

protected void dgvCredits_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach (GridViewRow row in dgvCredits.Rows)
{
if (row.RowIndex == dgvCredits.SelectedIndex)
{
row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Aqua;
row.ToolTip = string.Empty;
GlobalVariables.oldrowindex = dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
txtOldRowIndex.Value = dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex.ToString();
}
else
{
row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
}
}
DisplayValues(); 
}

private void dgvCredits_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DisplayValues(); 
}

private void btnSearchCredits_Click(object p, EventArgs empty)
{
SQL.AddParam("@Credible_ID", txtSrchCredible_ID.Text);
SQL.AddParam("@ADP_ID", txtSrchADP_ID.Text);
SQL.AddParam("@Start_Date", txtSrchStart_Date.Text);
SQL.AddParam("@End_Date", txtSrchEnd_Date.Text);
{
CreditsLoadGrid(@"select Credits_ID, Credible_ID, ADP_ID, Employee_ID, Start_Date, End_Date, Reason, Units, Percentage, Other, RecordActive, CreatedBy, CreateDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedDate from Credits where (@Start_Date = '' or Start_Date = @Start_Date) or (@End_Date = '' or End_Date = @End_Date) order by Credible_ID, Start_Date;");
}
}
private void DisplayValues()
{
if (dgvCredits.Rows.Count > 0)
{
// 0 [Credits_ID]
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text is object)
{
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text == "&nbsp;")
txtCredits_ID.Text = ""; 
else
 txtCredits_ID.Text = dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text.ToString(); 
}
// 1 [Credible_ID]
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text is object)
{
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text == "&nbsp;")
txtCredible_ID.Text = ""; 
else
txtCredible_ID.Text = dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString(); 
}
// 2 [ADP_ID]
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text is object)
{
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text == "&nbsp;")
txtADP_ID.Text = ""; 
else
txtADP_ID.Text = dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString(); 
}
// 3 [Employee_ID]
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text is object)
{
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text == "&nbsp;")
txtEmployee_ID.Text = ""; 
else
txtEmployee_ID.Text = dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text.ToString(); 
}
// 4 [Start_Date]
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text is object)
{
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text == "&nbsp;")
txtStart_Date.Text = ""; 
else
txtStart_Date.Text = dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text.ToString(); 
}
// 5 [End_Date]
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[5].Text is object)
{
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[5].Text == "&nbsp;")
txtEnd_Date.Text = "";
else
txtEnd_Date.Text = dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[5].Text.ToString(); 
}
// 6 [Reason]
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[6].Text is object)
{
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[6].Text == "&nbsp;")
txtReason.Text = ""; 
else
txtReason.Text = dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[6].Text.ToString(); 
}
// 7 [Units]
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[7].Text is object)
{
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[7].Text == "&nbsp;")
txtUnits.Text = ""; 
else
txtUnits.Text = dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[7].Text.ToString(); 
}
// 8 [Perentage]
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[8].Text is object)
{
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[8].Text == "&nbsp;")
txtPercentage.Text = ""; 
else
txtPercentage.Text = dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[8].Text.ToString(); 
}
// 9 [Other]
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[9].Text is object)
{
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[9].Text == "&nbsp;")
txtOther.Text = ""; 
else
txtOther.Text = dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[9].Text.ToString(); 
}
// 10 [RecordActive]
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[10].Text is object)
{
//chkbxRecordActive.Checked = Conversions.ToBoolean(dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[10].Text.ToString()); 
chkbxRecordActive.Checked = true; 
}
// 11 [CreatedBy]
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[11].Text is object)
{
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[11].Text == "&nbsp;")
txtCreatedBy.Text = ""; 
else
txtCreatedBy.Text = dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[11].Text.ToString(); 
}
// 12 [CreateDate]
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[12].Text is object)
{
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[12].Text == "&nbsp;")
txtCreateDate.Text = ""; 
else
txtCreateDate.Text = dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[12].Text.ToString(); 
}
// 13 [ModifiedBy]
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[13].Text is object)
{
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[13].Text == "&nbsp;")
txtModifiedBy.Text = ""; 
else
txtModifiedBy.Text = dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[13].Text.ToString(); 
}
// 14 [ModifiedDate]
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[14].Text is object)
{
if (dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[14].Text == "&nbsp;")
txtModifiedDate.Text = ""; 
else
txtModifiedDate.Text = dgvCredits.Rows[dgvCredits.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Cells[14].Text.ToString(); 
}
}
} // DisplayValues

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ChangeButtons(null, EventArgs.Empty);
ChangeFields(null, EventArgs.Empty);
ClearFields(null, EventArgs.Empty);
GlobalVariables.updatetype = "Add";
txtSavedCredits_ID.Value = txtCredits_ID.Text;
txtCredible_ID.Focus();
}

protected void Insert()
{
string conString = GlobalVariables.strConnection;
string query = "INSERT Credits (Credible_ID,ADP_ID,Employee_ID,Start_Date,End_Date,Reason,Units,Percentage," +
"Other,RecordActive,CreatedBy,CreateDate,ModifiedBy,ModifiedDate " +
"VALUES (@Credible_ID,@ADP_ID,@Employee_ID,@Start_Date,@End_Date,@Reason,@Units,@Percentage," +
"@Other,@RecordActive,@CreatedBy,@CreateDate,@ModifiedBy,@ModifiedDate";
using (SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, dbconn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Credible_ID", txtCredible_ID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADP_ID", txtADP_ID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_ID", txtEmployee_ID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start_Date", txtStart_Date.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End_Date", txtEnd_Date.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", txtReason.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Units", txtUnits.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Percentage", txtPercentage.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Other", txtOther.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordActive", "1");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", Environment.UserName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", DateTime.Now);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifiedBy", Environment.UserName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifiedDate", DateTime.Now);
dbconn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
dbconn.Close();
}
}

protected void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ChangeButtons(null, EventArgs.Empty);
ChangeFields(null, EventArgs.Empty);
GlobalVariables.updatetype = "Copy";
txtStart_Date.Text = "";
txtEnd_Date.Text = "";
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now; 
DateTime firstDayOfMonth = DateTimeExtensions.FirstOfMonth(currentDate);
firstDayOfMonth = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
DateTime lastDayOfMonth = DateTimeExtensions.LastOfMonth(firstDayOfMonth);
txtEnd_Date.Text = lastDayOfMonth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
txtStart_Date.Text = firstDayOfMonth.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}

protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ChangeButtons(null, EventArgs.Empty);
ChangeFields(null, EventArgs.Empty);
GlobalVariables.updatetype = "Edit";
}

protected void Update()
{
string conString = GlobalVariables.strConnection;
conString = "Data Source=mssql.alliancehs.org;Initial Catalog=Productivity;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=1000;";
string query = "UPDATE Credits SET Credible_ID = @Credible_ID,ADP_ID = @ADP_ID,Employee_ID = @Employee_ID," +
"Start_Date = @Start_Date,End_Date = @End_Date,Reason = @Reason,Units = @Units,Percentage = @Percentage," +
"Other = @Other,RecordActive = @RecordActive,CreatedBy = @CreatedBy,CreateDate = @CreateDate,ModifiedBy = @ModifiedBy,ModifiedDate = @ModifiedDate " +
"WHERE Credits_ID = @Credits_ID";
using (SqlConnection dbconn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, dbconn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Credits_ID", txtCredits_ID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Credible_ID", txtCredible_ID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADP_ID", txtADP_ID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_ID", txtEmployee_ID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start_Date", txtStart_Date.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End_Date", txtEnd_Date.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", txtReason.Text);
if (txtUnits.Text != "") 
{ 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Units", txtUnits.Text);
}
else
{
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Units", DBNull.Value);
}
if (txtPercentage.Text != "")
{
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Percentage", txtPercentage.Text);
}
else
{
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Percentage", DBNull.Value);
}
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Other", txtOther.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordActive", chkbxRecordActive.Checked);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", txtCreatedBy.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", txtCreateDate.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifiedBy", Environment.UserName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifiedDate", DateTime.Now);
dbconn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
dbconn.Close();
}
}

protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
GlobalVariables.updatetype = "Delete";
GlobalVariables.updatetype = "";
}

protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ChangeButtons(null, EventArgs.Empty);
ChangeFields(null, EventArgs.Empty);
dgvCredits.DataBind();
if (GlobalVariables.updatetype == "Edit")
{
dgvCredits.SelectRow(GlobalVariables.oldrowindex);
if (int.TryParse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart(), out GlobalVariables.oldrowindex))
{
dgvCredits.SelectRow(int.Parse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart()));
}
}
if (GlobalVariables.updatetype == "Add")
{
dgvCredits.SelectRow(GlobalVariables.oldrowindex);
if (int.TryParse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart(), out GlobalVariables.oldrowindex))
{
dgvCredits.SelectRow(int.Parse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart()));
}
}
if (GlobalVariables.updatetype == "Copy")
{
dgvCredits.SelectRow(GlobalVariables.oldrowindex);
if (int.TryParse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart(), out GlobalVariables.oldrowindex))
{
dgvCredits.SelectRow(int.Parse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart()));
}
}
GlobalVariables.updatetype = "";
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ChangeButtons(null, EventArgs.Empty);
ChangeFields(null, EventArgs.Empty);
if (GlobalVariables.updatetype == "Edit")
Update();
if (GlobalVariables.updatetype == "Add")
Insert();
if (GlobalVariables.updatetype == "Copy")
Insert();
dgvCredits.DataBind();
if (GlobalVariables.updatetype == "Edit")
{
dgvCredits.SelectRow(GlobalVariables.oldrowindex);
if (int.TryParse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart(), out GlobalVariables.oldrowindex))
{
dgvCredits.SelectRow(int.Parse(txtOldRowIndex.Value.TrimStart()));
}
}
SqlCommand getMaxIDCmd;
string getMaxIDSQL;
SqlConnection DBConn = new SqlConnection();
if (GlobalVariables.logProd == 1)
GlobalVariables.strConnection = "ProductivityProdConnectionString";
else
GlobalVariables.strConnection = "ProductivityTestConnectionString";
DBConn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[GlobalVariables.strConnection].ConnectionString;
getMaxIDSQL = @"Select Max(Credits_ID) from Credits;";
DBConn.Open();
getMaxIDCmd = new SqlCommand(getMaxIDSQL, DBConn);
getMaxIDCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
GlobalVariables.MaxID = (int)getMaxIDCmd.ExecuteScalar();
DBConn.Close();
if (GlobalVariables.updatetype == "Copy")
dgvCredits.SelectRow(GlobalVariables.MaxID);
GlobalVariables.updatetype = "";
}

protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
}

protected void ChangeFields(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
txtSrchCredible_ID.Enabled = !txtSrchCredible_ID.Enabled;
txtSrchADP_ID.Enabled = !txtSrchADP_ID.Enabled;
txtSrchStart_Date.Enabled = !txtSrchStart_Date.Enabled;
txtSrchEnd_Date.Enabled = !txtSrchEnd_Date.Enabled;
txtCredible_ID.Enabled = !txtCredible_ID.Enabled;
txtADP_ID.Enabled = !txtADP_ID.Enabled;
txtEmployee_ID.Enabled = !txtEmployee_ID.Enabled;
txtStart_Date.Enabled = !txtStart_Date.Enabled;
txtEnd_Date.Enabled = !txtEnd_Date.Enabled;
txtReason.Enabled = !txtReason.Enabled;
txtUnits.Enabled = !txtUnits.Enabled;
txtPercentage.Enabled = !txtPercentage.Enabled;
txtOther.Enabled = !txtOther.Enabled;
}

protected void ChangeButtons(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
btnAdd.Enabled = !btnAdd.Enabled;
btnCopy.Enabled = !btnCopy.Enabled;
btnEdit.Enabled = !btnEdit.Enabled;
btnDelete.Enabled = !btnDelete.Enabled;
btnCancel.Enabled = !btnCancel.Enabled;
btnSave.Enabled = !btnSave.Enabled;
btnClose.Enabled = !btnClose.Enabled;
btnSearchCredits.Enabled = !btnSearchCredits.Enabled;
btnClearCredits.Enabled = !btnClearCredits.Enabled;
}

protected void ClearFields(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
txtCredits_ID.Text = "";
txtCredible_ID.Text = "";
txtADP_ID.Text = "";
txtEmployee_ID.Text = "";
txtStart_Date.Text = "";
txtEnd_Date.Text = "";
txtReason.Text = "";
txtUnits.Text = "";
txtPercentage.Text = "";
txtOther.Text = "";
txtCreateDate.Text = "";
txtCreatedBy.Text = "";
txtModifiedDate.Text = "";
txtModifiedBy.Text = "";
}

}
}
```

However this gets the old value. How do I get the new value the user input?

Comment: Practically impossible to answer this without having whole of your code. Try showing us a bit more as that may be a whole lotta of thing going on here. But quickly, I think it's related to the ASP.net lifecycle which reinterpret the code from the click event of the grid and then put it back in the textbox (such as on page load or something). Then, the click event is raised and then, you lost what was written here as that has been reloaded. This is a common mistake made with ASP.net.

Comment: added code for the save button and the update

Comment: Added the code of the entire web form. Perhaps someone can help now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having the whole portion of the code of that page, I'm guessing the problem is the ASP.net events. If it's not, my explanation may help someone else facing similar problem. But, let me trying to explain you this the best I can considering English is not my primary language.

The whole point here is not the HOW you save.
It is much more about HOW and WHEN you are filling the very "textbox" you are talking about so I guess the textbox with ID "txtOther".

I'm, again, guessing something like that maybe:

1. On Page_Load, you are loading value and everything which is feeding the grid.
2. Then, once user has its page loaded, he click on a line which make a postback and feed the txtOther.Text with desired value.

That being said, if it how you do this, it wont work. If you put a break point on the part you are loading value in the grid, you'll see that it is loading, at every postback, the value back to the textbox you think has it value changed by user.

Again, considering that I can't see how you load value, a way I know which can handle this problem, is where you are loading values on the page, to do it only once. Like that:

```
if (!Page.IsPostback) {
    // YOUR LOADING CODE HERE
}
```

This should prevents your values from being load on each postback.

Note: In you btnSave_Click event, consider adding a "using" on your DBConn.

Comment: I Added the code of the entire web form. it is a lot of code and did not think I would be able to do that. Any thoughts?

Comment: Honestly, it is hard to go through otherwise I can't test the whole thing. All I can say to you is to be aware of how you load values on first instance. Try putting breakpoint where you load values and where you retrieve it. Most important things, is that if you load values AFTER oninit (as in Page_Load), values writing but user WON'T be persisted because of viewstate/load priority. Try changing the whole thing so it is load PRIOR to OnInit and it should persist it.

Comment: I am marking your answer as correct. The if (!Page.IsPostback) is the fix. I couldn't see it because i had the "if (!Page.IsPostback)" in the code but discovered that it was within an if statement and the else part was not using the "if (!Page.IsPostback)". Put it in the else and it started working.

Comment: Have to always think of how values are loaded in order to get them persisted. Nice job!